# Issue with CFArrayRef and NSArray when drawing gradient using ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-graphics, automatic-ref-counting, core-foundation

I have an ARC project and am trying to draw a vertical linear gradient. The code below works on the simulator, but throws a memory /`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error when testing on the device. The app crashes on with the following two lines of code:

```
NSArray *colorArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(__bridge id)topColor, (__bridge id)bottomColor, nil];
CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (__bridge CFArrayRef) colorArray, colorLocations);
```

Those two lines of code are taken from the following code (provided for reference):

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    [self createGradientForContext:context andView:self.captionView];
    [self createGradientForContext:context andView:self.linksView];
    [self createGradientForContext:context andView:self.commentView]; 

}

- (void)createGradientForContext:(CGContextRef)context andView:(UIView *)view
{

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    CGFloat colorLocations[] = { 0.0f, 1.0f };

    CGColorRef topColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:51.0f/255.0f green:51.0f/255.0f blue:51.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor];
    CGColorRef bottomColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:48.0f/255.0f green:48.0f/255.0f blue:48.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor];
    NSArray *colorArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(__bridge id)topColor, (__bridge id)bottomColor, nil];
    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (__bridge_retained CFArrayRef) colorArray, colorLocations);    

    CGRect frame = view.frame;
    CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame));
    CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(frame), CGRectGetMaxY(frame));

    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextAddRect(context, frame);
    CGContextClip(context);
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    CGGradientRelease(gradient);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

}
```

Thanks ahead of time for any and all guidance.

Comment: Don't you love arc? Taking away programmer control of memory... I thought Apple learned their lesson with garbage collection. I would recommend not using it...

Comment: I would recommend using ARC, there really needs to be a compelling reason not to.

Comment: Why are you using an object there when everything else is a `CFType`? Just use `CFArray` and you don't have to worry about bridging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try just using a `CFArrayRef` and avoid the bridging and see whether it makes a difference.

```
CGFloat topColorComps[] = {51.0f/255.0f, 51.0f/255.0f, 51.0f/255.0f, 1.0f};
CGFloat bottomColorComps[] = {48.0f/255.0f, 48.0f/255.0f, 48.0f/255.0f, 1.0f};            

CGColorSpaceRef rgb = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGColorRef topColor = CGColorCreate(rgb, topColorComps);
CGColorRef bottomColor = CGColorCreate(rgb, bottomColorComps);
CGColorSpaceRelease(rgb);

CFMutableArrayRef colorArray = CFArrayCreateMutable(NULL, 2, &kCFTypeArrayCallbacks);
CFArrayAppendValue(colorArray, topColor);
CFArrayAppendValue(colorArray, bottomColor);

CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, colorArray, colorLocations);

CFRelease(colorArray);
CFRelease(topColor);
CFRelease(bottomColor);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sadly, it crashes on `CFArrayAppendValue(colorArray, topColor)` when running it on my device.

Comment: @ArtSabintsev: The problem could be the use of `UIColor`. I've edited the example above, this time, you own everything.

Comment: thanks! Now I'm getting `CGColorCreateGenericRGB is unavailable`. Looking into this.

Comment: @ArtSabintsev: Oh bugger, that's a Mac OS X only function, just a minute, I'll update again.

Comment: Casing error in this answer - should be `&kCFTypeArrayCallBacks`

Answer (score 8):

Now to explain why you were crashing…

The problem is these two lines:

> ```
> CGColorRef topColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:51.0f/255.0f green:51.0f/255.0f blue:51.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor];
> CGColorRef bottomColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:48.0f/255.0f green:48.0f/255.0f blue:48.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor];
> ```

This is a very common problem; there are many questions on Stack Overflow by users who've gotten bitten by this.

The problem is that because those UIColor objects are never referenced after those lines, ARC releases them immediately—and because those UIColor objects are the sole owners of the CGColor objects, the UIColors release the CGColors immediately, leaving you with two dead CGColor objects. Which you then try to put into an array.

As you found, switching from NSArray to pure CFArray will not fix this. Switching from UIColor to pure CGColor is one solution; the other is to put your own ownership on the CGColors:

```
CGColorRef topColor = CGColorRetain([[UIColor colorWithRed:51.0f/255.0f green:51.0f/255.0f blue:51.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor]);
CGColorRef bottomColor = CGColorRetain([[UIColor colorWithRed:48.0f/255.0f green:48.0f/255.0f blue:48.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor]);

⋮

CGColorRelease(topColor);
CGColorRelease(bottomColor);
```

Comment: +1 for correct technical answer.  For me, a better solution is to use UIColor right up until the point you create the array:

[NSArray arrayWithObjects:(__bridge id)startColour.CGColor, (__bridge id)endColour.CGColor, nil];

Comment: @Cthutu: That does effectively the same as retaining them yourself—in that case, the array retains them. For non-gradient purposes, passing `myUIColor.CGColor` directly to `CGContextSetFillColorWithColor` or similar (as opposed to stashing it in a `CGColorRef` variable and then retrieving it from there) should also work, if that function either retains the color object or does not attempt to keep it.

Comment: Yes it's exactly the same thing but you don't need all the CGColorRelease() calls.  The releasing is done in ARC, and not a Core Foundation call.

Comment: @Cthutu: Well, the releasing of the UIColor and the array is done in ARC, and the releasing of the CGColor is done by the array (which may or may not be ARC on the inside). But yeah. Same difference all around.

Comment: One more option is to `CGColorRetain(theColorRef)`, and `(__bridge_transfer id)theColorRef` when stuffing into the array.  This will tell ARC that the object is already retained, but needs to be released by ARC at a later time.

Comment: @MattH.: Another way to do the latter step is `CFBridgingRelease`.